# Jsessionid Jmeter after login to site

Tags: jmeter-4.0

what should i do to corelate i can use different login in jmeter i have already parameterize the value. i am getting stuck with this jsession id

Sample Count: 1
Error Count: 0
Data type ("text"|"bin"|""): text
Response code: 200
Response message: OK

Response headers:
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
X-AREQUESTID: 340x9129744x1
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
X-ASEN: SEN-1047238
Set-Cookie: atlassian.xsrf.token=AVWR-AYBS-V3UU-QQRS|fef17187ee7e13e93c498a08e44fb5c2b90aba75|lout; Path=/
X-AUSERNAME: anonymous
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=3075A3A258CBA5D6131F724E3C0800CC; Path=/; HttpOnly
X-Accel-Buffering: no
Vary: User-Agent
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Sun, 07 Oct 2018 09:40:27 GMT
Content-Encoding: gzip

HTTPSampleResult fields:
ContentType: text/html;charset=UTF-8
DataEncoding: UTF-8

Comment: What's the question? what have you tried?

Comment: i am using post processor regular expression extractor

Comment: Set-Cookie: xsrf.token=(.*?);  as regular expression

Comment: what about session id?

Comment: thanks, Jmeter itself  handled the jession and token it didt have to modify those.